# FOR XML could not serialize the data because it contains character (0x0000)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xml

I have a big query (if necessary I will post it here) and I'm getting this error:

> Msg 6841, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   FOR XML could not serialize the
>   data for node 'NoName' because it contains a character (0x0000) which
>   is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it
>   to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64
>   directive.

The only part I use `FOR XML` is here:

```
WHERE 
    (CodFuncionario = Results.CodFuncionario) 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 
    'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS [Experiencia]
```

But, what is `node noname`? and how can I look for this value: `(0x0000)`

This is one of the subqueries (the only part I have FOR XML):

```
SELECT 
    [CodFuncionario],
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ' / ' + 
            CAST
            (
                [DescFuncao] + '-' + 
                [DescTempoExperiencia] 
                AS VARCHAR(MAX)
            )...
FROM 
    [Linked_Server].db.dbo.tblFuncionarioExperiencia T0
INNER JOIN
    [Linked_Server].db.dbo.tblFuncao T1 On T0.codFuncao = T1.CodFuncao
INNER JOIN
    [Linked_Server].db.dbo.tblTempoExperiencia T2 ON T0.CodTempoExperiencia = T2.CodTempoExperiencia 
WHERE 
   (CodFuncionario = Results.CodFuncionario) 
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS [Experiencia]
  FROM 
      [Linked_Server].db.dbo.tblFuncionarioExperiencia Results  
  GROUP BY 
      CodFuncionario) as T2

  On T0.CodFuncionario = T2.CodFuncionario

Left Join...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line:

```
...
SELECT 
    [CodFuncionario],
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ' / ' + 
                CAST
                (
                    [DescFuncao] + '-' + 
                    [DescTempoExperiencia] 
                    AS VARCHAR(MAX)
                )...
```

Should be:

```
...
SELECT 
    [CodFuncionario],
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ' / ' + 
                CAST
                (
                    replace -- *** NEW! ***
                    (
                        [DescFuncao] + '-' + 
                        [DescTempoExperiencia],
                        char(0),
                        ''
                    ) 
                    AS VARCHAR(MAX)
                )...
```

Answer (score 12):

I get the same error when I do this:

```
DECLARE @foo VARCHAR(32) = CHAR(0); -- 0x0000
SELECT @foo FOR XML PATH, TYPE;
```

So, find all instances of `DescFuncao` or `DescTempoExperiencia` (sorry, you don't use table aliasing, so it's impossible to tell which table they come from) where the contents contain `CHAR(0)`, and fix them. For example:

```
UPDATE dbo.whatever 
  SET DescFuncao = REPLACE(DescFuncao, CHAR(0), '')
  WHERE DescFuncao LIKE '%' + CHAR(0) + '%';
```

It's not enough to filter those rows out in your query, because you don't know at what point the XML methods will go to work, but you may also try:

```
STUFF(( SELECT ' / ' + CAST(REPLACE([DescFuncao] + '-' 
  + [DescTempoExperiencia], CHAR(0), '') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Of course, fixing the source data *once* will be much more efficient than running these replace routines *every time*.

Note, this might not be the only specific character that causes this problem. `0x0001` -> `0x0008` will also generate the same error. So if you have those characters in there too, you should investigate where they are coming from, and fix the source.

Answer (score 11):

I tested this with ASCII characters 0-255 and found out that you get this error for characters: `0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004, 0x0005, 0x0006, 0x0007, 0x0008, 0x000B, 0x000C, 0x000E, 0x000F, 0x0010, 0x0011, 0x0012, 0x0013, 0x0014, 0x0015, 0x0016, 0x0017, 0x0018, 0x0019, 0x001A, 0x001B, 0x001C, 0x001D, 0x001E, 0x001F`.

One workaround is to remove `, TYPE` from your XML statement.

Another way is to remove those characters in the select statement:

```
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
    < YOUR EXPRESSION TO BE CLEANED >
,char(0x0000),'') ,char(0x0001),'') ,char(0x0002),'') ,char(0x0003),'') ,char(0x0004),'') 
,char(0x0005),'') ,char(0x0006),'') ,char(0x0007),'') ,char(0x0008),'') ,char(0x000B),'') 
,char(0x000C),'') ,char(0x000E),'') ,char(0x000F),'') ,char(0x0010),'') ,char(0x0011),'') 
,char(0x0012),'') ,char(0x0013),'') ,char(0x0014),'') ,char(0x0015),'') ,char(0x0016),'') 
,char(0x0017),'') ,char(0x0018),'') ,char(0x0019),'') ,char(0x001A),'') ,char(0x001B),'') 
,char(0x001C),'') ,char(0x001D),'') ,char(0x001E),'') ,char(0x001F),'')
```

You could also create a function with these replace statements.

Comment: This script is useful (though painfully slow), but it doesn't work on emoji characters (such as 0xD83D), and I suspect that there might be a lot of them.... at least in my data.    :'(
Or should I say: 0x1F62D

Answer (score 4):

Optimizing [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148568) from jumxozizi by using `translate` (SQL Server 2017++).  The code below will replace those characters with periods.

```
declare
    @illegalChars nvarchar(4000) = 
        char(0) + char(1) + char(2) + char(3) + char(4) + char(5) + char(6) + char(7) + char(8) + char(11) + 
        char(12) + char(14) + char(15) + char(16) + char(17) + char(18) + char(19) + char(20) + char(21) + char(22) + 
        char(23) + char(24) + char(25) + char(26) + char(27) + char(28) + char(29) + char(30) + char(31);

select translate(input, @illegalChars, replicate('.', len(@illegalChars))) as Result
```

To strip them instead, one could translate() them first to char(0) and then wrap that with a replace().

From idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55906638/538763

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a full example of what crokusek [suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241812) to optimize jumxozizi's even more original [suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148568).

This carries out the combined suggestion of `replace` and `translate` together.

In my example, I had a field where I knew I wanted to find and replace two of the "illegal" characters in the column `description`. So, it's not *completely* related to the OP's post, but this is why I ended up here and hopefully this fleshing out of crokusek's answer is helpful!

```
declare
    @illegalChars nvarchar(4000) = 
        char(0) + char(1) + char(2) + char(3) + char(4) + char(5) + char(6) + char(7) 
        + char(8) + char(11) + char(12) + char(14) + char(15) + char(16) + char(17) 
        + char(18) + char(19) + char(20) + char(21) + char(22) + char(23) + char(24)  
        + char(25) + char(26) + char(27) + char(28) + char(29) + char(30) + char(31);

SELECT TOP (100) 
       [id]
      ,replace(
        translate(
         description, 
         @illegalChars, 
         replicate(CHAR(0), len(@illegalChars))
        ), 
        CHAR(0), 
        ''
       )
  FROM <table name here>
  WHERE 
     (RTRIM(description) LIKE '%' + CHAR(2) +  '%') 
  OR (RTRIM(description) LIKE '%' + CHAR(11) +  '%');
```